# Unable to install/run docker-ce on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm having an absolute nightmare installing docker-ce.

I had a previous install running on my machine which was misbehaving, it was running an old version so I decided to just uninstall and reinstall the latest version.

to completely uninstall the old version and anything else that may be lurking I ran:

`sudo apt purge docker docker-ce docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

Then to install the latest version I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

The installation fails with:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-10 12:37:15 BST; 11ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 6990 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 6990 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.21) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

trying to start docker fails and systemctl status docker.service shows:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-05-10 12:39:07 BST; 36s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 7628 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7628 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 10 12:39:07 accuheat-nuc systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Any ideas what the problem might be or how I can investigate it further?